# If $\cos(A+B+C)=\cos A\cos B\cos C\neq 0$, then evaluate $\left|\frac{8\sin(A+B)\sin(B+C)\sin(C+A)}{\sin 2A\sin 2B\sin 2C}\right|$

Tags: trigonometry

> If 
>   $$\cos(A+B+C)=\cos A\cos B\cos C,  \quad\text{with}\;A,B,C\neq \frac{k\pi}{2}$$
>   then 
>   $$\left|\frac{8\sin(A+B)\sin(B+C)\sin(C+A)}{\sin 2A\sin 2B\sin 2C}\right|$$ is what integer?

What I tried:

$$\begin{align}
\cos(A+B+C)
&=\cos A \cos B \cos C - \sin A \sin B \sin C - \sin C \sin A \cos B - \sin B \sin C \cos A \\
&=\cos A\cos B\cos C\left(1-\tan A\tan B-\tan B\tan C-\tan C\tan A\right)
\end{align}$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, where you have left off,

$$pq+qr+rp=0$$   writing  $\tan A=p,\tan B=q,\tan C=r$

we have $p,q,r$ are non-zero and finite

Now $$\dfrac{2\sin(A+B)}{\sin2C}=\cdots=\dfrac{p+q}{r}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{2\sin(A+B)\cdot2\sin(B+C)\cdot2\sin(C+A)}{\sin2A\sin2B\sin2C}$$

$$=\dfrac{(p+q)(q+r)(r+p)}{pqr}$$

$$=\dfrac{2pqr+p(pq+qr+rp)-pqr+q(pq+qr+rp)-pqr+r(pq+qr+rp)-pqr}{pqr}$$

$$=\dfrac{pqr(2-3)}{pqr}=?$$

Answer (score 3):

Using $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ along with $\sin(A+B)=\sin(\pi-C)=\sin(C)$ and $\cos(A)\cos(B)\cos(C)=\cos(A+B+C)=\cos(\pi)=-1$ should give the value as $1$.